# How to get a date month ago depending on a constant start date?

Tags: javascript

I need to render a subscription date range on a page like this:

31 May 2023 — 30 June 2023

When user subscribes then backend sends a subscription start date (it never changes and always the same). For example if user subscribed on 31 May 2023 then the start date will be:

```
const startDate = "2023-05-31T10:16:14+00:00"
```

Then there're `nextDates` when a new credits will be added to user account

```
  const nextDate = "2023-06-30T10:16:20.404358+00:00",
  const nextDate1 = "2023-07-31T10:16:20.404358+00:00",
  const nextDate2 = "2023-08-31T10:16:20.404358+00:00",
```

So my question is how can I get the start date for each `nextDate`?
The output should be like this:

```
const startDate = "2023-05-31T10:16:14+00:00"
const nextDate = "2023-06-30T10:16:20.404358+00:00" // startDate should be 31 May 2023
const nextDate1 = "2023-07-31T10:16:20.404358+00:00" // startDate should be 30 June 2023
```

I tried this but the output is incorrect:

```
const getPreviousInterval = (nextDate, months) => {
  const date = new Date(nextDate);
  const dateMonthsAgoUnix = date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - months);

  return new Date(dateMonthsAgoUnix);
};

getPreviousInterval("2023-06-30T10:16:20.404358+00:00", 1);
// incorrect output is 2023-05-30T10:16:20.404Z
// correct output is 2023-05-31T10:16:14+00:00
```

Comment: What about if they subscribe on the first or mid-month? Can you provide a list of inputs and expected outputs for various days?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const date = new Date(Date.now());
const oneMonthAgo = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1));

console.log(oneMonthAgo);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// gets today's date
const date = new Date();

// gets the date from one month ago
const oneMonthAgo = new Date();
oneMonthAgo.setMonth(oneMonthAgo.getMonth() - 1);

console.log("Today's date is " + date.toLocaleDateString() + ".");
console.log("One month ago, the date was " + oneMonthAgo.toLocaleDateString() + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want the last day of the previous calendar month rather than something "one month ago".  See details of setDate(0) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#description).

```js
const getPreviousInterval = (nextDate, months) => {
  const date = new Date(nextDate);
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - months + 1);
  date.setDate(0); // setDate(0) gives the last day of the previous month
  return date;
};

console.log(getPreviousInterval("2023-06-30T10:16:20.404358+00:00", 1));

console.log(getPreviousInterval("2023-06-30T10:16:20.404358+00:00", 4));

console.log(getPreviousInterval("2023-06-30T10:16:20.404358+00:00", 40));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a list of future dates by adding a month to the date and then one day in milliseconds each time.

You can then use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` class to format the date in British format.

```js
const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB',  // UK date format
  { day: '2-digit', month: 'short', year: 'numeric' }); // DD MMM YYYY

const formatDateRange = (fromDate, toDate) =>
  `${dateFormatter.format(fromDate)} — ${dateFormatter.format(toDate)}`;

const computeFutureMonths = (startDate, months) => {
  const results = [], currDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
  for (let i = 0; i < months; i++) {
    currDate.setMonth(currDate.getMonth() + 1);
    results.push(new Date(currDate.getTime() - 8.64e7)); // Subtract 1 day in ms
  }
  return results;
};

const startDate = new Date('2023-05-31T10:16:14+00:00');
const nextThreeMonths = computeFutureMonths(startDate, 3);

nextThreeMonths.forEach(date => {
  console.log(date.toISOString());
});

// 31 May 2023 — 30 Jun 2023
console.log(formatDateRange(startDate, nextThreeMonths[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most answers here suggest subtracting a month, but this doesn't work as you would expect..

```js
const d = new Date("2023-05-31T10:16:14+00:00");
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() -1);
console.log(d);
//result "2023-05-01T10:16:14.000Z"
```

Notice how the Date is the 1st,

But another easier way to get end of previous month, is set the date to 0.

eg.

```js
const d = new Date("2023-05-31T10:16:14+00:00");
d.setDate(0);
console.log(d);
//result "2023-04-30T10:16:14.000Z"
```

If you want to go back more months, then you could use `setMonth` for all but 1, and then `setDate(0)` for the last.

eg. 3 months.

```js
const d = new Date("2023-05-31T10:16:14+00:00");
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() -2);
d.setDate(0);
console.log(d);
//result "2023-02-28T11:16:14.000Z"
```

> If nextDate is 2023-06-05T10:16:20.404358+00:00 then output should be
> 2023-05-05T10:16:20.404358+00:00...how can I handle this case?

For this case you will want to check if the current date is less than the date we currently get, because 31 can be bigger than other months.  If it is, then you can then just set the Date to the old date.

eg.

```js
const d = new Date("2023-06-05T10:16:20.404358+00:00");
const oldDate = d.getDate();
d.setDate(0);
if (oldDate < d.getDate()) d.setDate(oldDate);
console.log(d);
//result "2023-05-05T10:16:20.404Z"
```

Comment: If `nextDate` is `2023-06-05T10:16:20.404358+00:00` then output should be `2023-05-05T10:16:20.404358+00:00`...how can I handle this case?

Comment: @qweezz  Just set the date if it's less than the number of days in the new month.  Updated answer with another snippet showing this.